# Difference between limits at infinity and at negative infinity

Tags: limits

Notice that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-6x +1}-x = -3$$
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2-6x +1}-x = \infty$$

On manipulating the function by rationalization, I get:
$$\frac{-6+\frac1x}{\sqrt{1-\frac6x +\frac1{x^2}}+1}$$

What is the difference between $x$ approaching $\infty$ and x approaching $-\infty$? From what I see, all $x$ terms should approach $0$ regardless of whether $x$ approaches $\infty$ or approaches $-\infty$.
What is wrong with this thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ (and not simply $x$). For $x\not=0$,
$$\sqrt{x^2-6x +1}-x=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2-6x +1})^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-6x +1}+x}=\frac{-6x +1}{\sqrt{x^2}\cdot \sqrt{1-6/x +1/x^2}+x}\\
=\frac{-6 +\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{|x|}{x}\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac6x +\frac1{x^2}}+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
remember that:
$$a\sqrt{b}=\mbox{sign} (a)\sqrt{a^2b}$$

and,  $x\to - \infty \Rightarrow x<0$,  so you have a term $\mbox{sign} (1/x)=-1$ when you calculate : $\lim _{x \to - \infty}$